# Is it possible to delete/hide extra lines in NetBeans IDE output screen? If possible then how?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

[image]

I just want to get program's output in output screen. I want to get rid of the extra lines.
Please help me if you have the solution. [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgQVb.png)

Answer (score 3):

Run the `mvn` command using `--quiet` or `-q` parameter:

```
mvn --quiet ...
```

or

```
mvn -q ... ...
```

If you want to suppress the display of transfer progress when downloading or uploading, use `--no-transfer-progress` or `-ntp`:

```
mvn --no-transfer-progress ....
```

or

```
mvn -ntp ... ....
```

Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html) for reference.

Click the **Maven Settings** button shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Type **-q** in the box shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Press **OK** button and then run your class.

Comment: This doesn't wok for me. I still get output from NetBeans in the Output window:  `cd D:\NB112\mavenproject9; JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_221 cmd /c "\"\"C:\\NetBeans112\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.unthreading.mavenproject9.App\" -Dexec.executable=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_221\\bin\\java.exe -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\NetBeans112\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar -q org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On ...[text discarded]... (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.`

Comment: Also, this approach does not work at all for Ant projects or Gradle projects.

Comment: Liked. Pity can't get rid of beginning cd ... lines as well :)

Answer (score 1):

[Simply Put "-q" in "global execution options" in maven setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFMJr.png)

Simply Put "-q" in "Global execution options" in maven setting!

Comment: Can you explain what is in this Answer that is not also in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168175/12695027) by [Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash)?

Comment: I kept it simple in a single line :)

Comment: How does that add value? You've just posted what is already in the thread.

Comment: Let it be! Do you want any change in it?

Answer (score 0):

Following @skomisa idea I added -l log.txt (in Maven settings @Arvind Kumar Avinash) and detached a window showing log.txt (use files tab to see it).

It worked quite well, though I wasn't sure how to keep it on top, so resized main NetBeans window.

What is useful is that the font size now follows the editor window which makes it useful for displaying to a class. :)

Edit: split the editor windows -  drag the log.txt window to the far right and release - two open editor window :)

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Multiple sources write to the Output window in NetBeans. It would be difficult to track them all down, and probably impossible to prevent all of them writing to the Output window for all project types, but even if you could do that it wouldn't really be a good idea because if there was a problem you wouldn't get any diagnostics at all.

However, there is a simple alternative approach that may (or may not) be acceptable to you:

- Instead of preventing all other sources from writing to the Output window, just create a separate `PrintStream` for your application's output.
- If you make that new `PrintStream` a project file, you can have it open in NetBeans and see it updated as you run your project.
- To create the `PrintStream` as a project file use this form of its constructors: `PrintStream ps2 = new PrintStream("MyOutput.txt");` which will create a file named **MyOutput.txt** directly under the root of your project.

Here's a trivial application which does that:

```
package output;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Output {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintStream ps2 = new PrintStream("MyOutput.txt");
            ps2.println("abcdef");
            ps2.println("This text is not going to the Output window!!!!");
            System.out.println("Hello world");            
    }
}
```

Each time you run the application the content of the edit window for MyOutput.txt is refreshed:

[image: PrintStreamOutput]

Notes:

- You can still (optionally) direct output to the Output window using `System.out` and `System.err` if you wish.
- If you later want to redirect your application's output to the Output window, just modify the declaration of the `PrintStream` like this: `PrintStream ps2 = new PrintStream(System.out, true);`