# Netbeans 18 output

Tags: java, netbeans

I code in maven java in netbeans 18 and my netbeans18 IDE shows output like image1 but i want to see outputs like image 2 so what should I do now?

[1st imnage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7yY2.png)[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNsia.png)

I tried many times but not working I want a clear solution.i also tried in pluging,tools,windows but not worked.

Comment: Try running the main class directly instead of starting with Maven. I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but in IntelliJ you would select a different type of run target (Java instead of Gradle/Maven)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to delete/hide extra lines in NetBeans IDE output screen? If possible then how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167631/is-it-possible-to-delete-hide-extra-lines-in-netbeans-ide-output-screen-if-poss)